# Authorize.Net Payment through bank accounts?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net, payment-processing

I am new to Payment Gateways and I didnt get relavant information for the followings,

My website users not ready to give payment through Credit Cards. and I would like to use Authroize.Net for my payment processing.

1. So, Authorize.Net will Support payment through Bank Accounts?.
2. If So, where do i find the list of banks supported by Authorize.Net?
3. If not so, Please suggest some Online Payment Gateway which support payment with Bank Accounts?

I found this " http://www.ccavenue.com/indianrupees.jsp ", which process online payment through Bank Account. But it offers only Inidian Banks. Please suggest for US Banks.

Answer (score 5):

Your confusion is a common problem in the online payments world. The industry does not do a good job of making this process clear. Here is how online payments work:

In order to accept credit cards online, you will need three elements, depending on how you will be taking those payments. I will assume you have products listed on your website for sale. If you will be taking phone orders or internet orders that require you to enter the information, it will only be slightly different.

1) You will need a shopping cart of some kind. A shopping cart compiles all of the purchases made on your website, adds up the total, and adds any appropriate taxes and shipping. It provides a total purchase price and presents that price to your customer.

2) You will need an internet gateway. As you have mentioned, Authorize.net is the big dog in the marketplace. It is simple to use and has a great reputation for security. Think of an internet gateway as a credit card terminal in cyberspace. All it does is collect your customer credit card information and hold it securely, just as a credit card terminal in a retail store does.

3) You will need a merchant account. The merchant account takes the information held by your gateway, and sends it out to all the appropriate banks that issued your customers' credit cards, collects the money, and turns around and deposits that money into your bank account to complete the sale.

The problem here is that each element - the shopping cart, the gateway, and the merchant account, need to be integrated so that they can "talk" to each other. The problem many merchants face is that they get their shopping cart from one place, their gateway from another place, and their merchant account from a third place. Then, no one knows how to integrate the three to talk with each other. The biggest culprit in this situation is the merchant account provider; many banks offer merchant processing, but they have NO IDEA how to integrate with Authorize.net, but they won't tell you that until you are already signed up. My advice would be to make absolutely certain that your merchant account provider knows how to integrate with a gateway from the beginning.

In terms of suggesting a merchant account provider, there are hundreds and hundreds available, and some are better than others. My advice would be to find a merchant processor who offers "pre-integrated" merchant accounts and gateways. That will help remove one of the most troubling aspects of setting up to take payments online, which is the process of getting both elements integrated.

I hope this helps you.

Sincerely,
Mike

Yadheendran - I forgot to add one other detail. If you are going to be taking orders by mail or over the phone, you probably will not use the classic "shopping cart" solution I mentioned above, but will probably need some sort of ordering software. The bottom line here, however, is that the process works just the same as with a shopping cart. Most shopping carts and ordering software integrate very, very easily with Authorize.net, as most software is designed specifically to accept Authorize.net as a gateway because it is so incredibly popular. Sorry to have forgotten to mention this before.

Comment: Can we debit a bank account via authorize.net on android ??